# Abnormal feature of Java where Multiple Inheritance is visible

Tags: java, inheritance

The Oracle docs states very clearly that Java Language has no Multiple Inheritance feature i.e. Any class declared in Java cannot inherit features from two separate classes.
But there lies a statement that Class Object is the super class of every other class created by user.
Consider a sample Class as follows:

```
Class Base {
.....
}

Class Derived extends Base {
.....
}
```

Now if we look onto Class Derived then it is clearly visible that it inherits from Class Base and also from Class Object, then that proves that Java does has Multiple Inheritance.

**Solution as provided from one of the pages of Oracle Sites**

```
Excepting Object, which has no superclass, 
every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). 
In the absence of any other explicit superclass, 
every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.
```

This means that any class which doesn't have a single-inheritance available will only have an implicit single-inheritance with Class Object.

**Refer**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: It is Multilevel inheritance not Multiple Inheritance.

Comment: No my friend... Class Derived doesnt directly extend Object... The Highest Level parent of class Derived extends Object. i.e, here Base extends object.

Comment: I can't see any thing like multiple inheritance here. We normally call multiple inheritance if one class has more than one parent class. `Java` never ever had that.

Comment: `Derived -> Base -> Object`

Comment: Java does not have multiple inheritance. `Base` inherits from `Object`, if it isn't one of the primitive types (or an enum) then it is an Object in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466783/multiple-inheritance)

Comment: @gowtham - Please remember that interfaces were not introduced to support multiple inheritance in Java.

Comment: ya Agreed and corrected myself

Comment: My question is mistaken. Before I get further down votes, I would like to share a material read from Oracle Sites
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/object-142075.html#6681

"Ultimately, all classes eventually inherit from the Object class, forming a tree structure with Object as its root."

Oracle sites clearly state that every class created by user has class Object as its superclass.

Comment: Please find the solution in the question section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could modify your code to

```
class Base extends Object{
.....
}

class Derived extends Base {
.....
}
```

So since only Base (and not Derived) extends Object, the class Derived inherits Object *through* Base, no multiple inheritance exists that way.

Answer (score 0):

If one `class` has(`extends` ) more than one parent `class` we called it as `multiple inheritance`. In `Java` never ever had that, In this case just a `multi level inheritance` not `multiple inheritance`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of **Multi-Level Inheritance** not **Multiple Inheritance**.

> Multiple Inheritance : we can inherit more than one class in the same class.

[image]

> Multi-Level Inheritance: where one class can inherit only one base
>   class and the derived class can become base class of some other class

[image]

Comment: Please find the solution in the question section

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can't extend from 2 separate class hierarchies. However, you can have multiple classes within a hierarchy. One class definition can have only one "extends" in it.

For example, `Mammal extends Animal` and `Dog extends Mammal` is acceptable. Dog will get the behaviors and states of Mammal and Animal (through Mammal).

What is not allowed is one class extending multiple classes.

So in your example, if you have 2 base classes BaseA and BaseB, class Derived cannot extend both BaseA and BaseB at the same time.

Comment: Please find the solution in the question section

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding inheritance.

[Multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) allows a class to inherit the properties of two distinct classes.  From Wikipedia, here is an illustration of one such hierarchy (known as the "diamond problem"):

[image]

Take note:  D is inheriting from both B and C.

To bring it to a better illustration, multiple inheritance would allow you to have a class structure like this:

```
public class Bike {
    // properties of a bike
}

public class Car {
    // properties of a car, namely that it has a motor
}

public class Moped extends Bike, Car {
    // properties inherited combine that it is both a Bike and a Car
}
```

The current way that Java classes are wired now is that their inheritance is [**hierarchal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_hierarchy); that is, one class may only ever have one parent class.

A good way to think of inheritance in this manner is the "is-a" relationship test.

For your example:

- A `Derived` **is a** `Base`.
- A `Base` **is an** `Object`.
- A `Derived` **is an** `Object`.

Comment: Please find the solution in the question section