# Is there an alternative for extending ListActivity in Android?

Tags: android, database, list, listview, mobile

I am extending `ListActivity` in one of my Activities but I need to extend one more `Activity`.

So, is there an alternative for extending `ListView` in Android?

I am using the `ListView` to display the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **Java does not support multiple inheritance**.

After this, what I would to, is to rethink in the design: *does it make sense to your class to be `ListActivity` and other `Activity`*?

If yes, there are a couple of workarounds you can try:

- **Aggregation**: make a class that takes those two activities as fields.
- [Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355408/explaining-interfaces-to-students).

Comment: Basically, I am asking how to use the methods of ListActivity by manually making an object of ListView

Comment: I must see more of your code to understand what you need exactly... [check this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) hope it clarifies... ;)

Comment: in the xml file in which I have used ListView, I have used something like this:
android:id="@+id/android:list"

How do I access it's id now?

Comment: you can reference it by `ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` then you can manipulate `mListView` as a normal Java object... But please, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list), to know more about referencing id's.