# What is the correct programming terminology for what I am calling interface?

Tags: c++, interface

I am finishing up my first semester of Programming Fundamentals. We have a final project of creating a software package using programs either that are in the textbook, previously created assignment programs, etc. I am using C++ Visual Studios 2013. I want to broaden my reach and create an application with, what I call a user interface (designed page that pops up after double clicking the desktop icon, that has a basic button named "Play"). Upon the user pressing "Play" button with the left mouse click, I'd like it to advance to another screen and execute the program. My question, what is the correct programming terminology to browse the web for what I want to do?

I saw this link that made me realize I was searching for the wrong thing.
[Explaining Interfaces to Students](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355408/explaining-interfaces-to-students)

Comment: Sounds like a "window".  A window is part of your program's User Interface (that is the correct term), but not all interfaces in software are with the user.  There are also interfaces between software components, or with the hardware, etc.

Comment: But I don't want a dos window that normally pops up when double clicking the .exe (application) file. Do I need to find different software? I saw this one that is C++ Builder by http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder

Comment: GUI? Graphic User Interface?

Comment: @ user3528438 - Hmmm..that would be fun. I did a search on that, and I think I'll see if I can incorporate my C++ program into something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A graphical user interface, or GUI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface

An *interface class* in C++ typically refers to an abstract class that acts as an interface for derived classes. Typically it has no data members or constructors and contains mostly pure virtual functions (as it cannot be instantiated alone).

Comment: Thank you for your help. You answered my question. I hope you all have a wonderful evening.